# Можно ли использовать в HTML-письмах нестандартные шрифты, не установленные в ОС?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли при вёрстке HTML-писем использовать нестандартные шрифты?

Comment: Можно. Но не нужно. Рискуете получить кашу вместо красивого форматирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать, но это будет работать только для IOS, Apple Mail.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/